# Highcharts: Display average hour values from a series of quarter-hourly values

Tags: highcharts

My weather station collects every 15 minutes the current temperature. With Highcharts I created a chart to display the last 24h. So I pass all the 96 quarter-hourly values to the chart. This looks not so pretty. Instead I would just display the average of each hour.

Is it possible to display the average value for each hour based on a series of quarter-hourly values and leaving the calculation to Highcharts and not doing it myself?

Answer (score 0):

You can use highstock which allows to use [datagrouping](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping).